# How to fix two rows at top when sorting a google visualization table?

Tags: javascript, sorting, charts, google-visualization

I have two rows in a google visualization table that I want to keep fixed at the top after a sort and then draw the table again.  I'm using:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
var table1 = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('my_div'));
var ascendOrDescend = true;
...
data.sort({column: colIndex, desc: ascendOrDescend});
ascendOrDescend = !ascendOrDescend;
table1.draw(data, options);
```

Is there a way to fix those two rows or after the sort force them back to the top?

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58541142/5090771)...

Comment: Thx. I read that one before I posted my question. The table1 you see in my code there is a google.visualization.Table, and has no setView() function. I have to manually sort some other way it seems.

Comment: To be more clear I have a google.visualization.Table and am calling the standard draw() function on it and providing it a google.visualization.DataTable object.  I'll edit the question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to fix a row at a certain position within the sort,
you need to manually control the sort order.

to control manually, set the following option when drawing the table.

```
var options = {
  sort: 'event'
};
```

the table's sort event will provide the column and direction requested by the user
you can pass the column and direction to data table method `getSortedRows`
which will return an array of row indexes that meet the sort criteria

```
// table sort event
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'sort', function (sender) {
  // get sorted rows indexes
  var sortIndexes = data.getSortedRows({column: sender.column, desc: !sender.ascending});
```

we can manipulate the array of row indexes by moving the row indexes we want at the top
and create a data view and use the `setRows` method to provide the order in which the data view should appear

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setRows(sortIndexes);
```

in order for the table to display the sort direction arrow above the correct column  we set the following table options

```
options.sortAscending = sender.ascending;
options.sortColumn = sender.column;
```

then draw the table using the newly created data view

see following working snippet,
the rows for `'Michael'` and `'Elisa'` will remain at the top after each sort

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'table']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Name', 'RoolNumber', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Donuts eaten'],
    ['Michael', 1, 'Male', 12, 5],
    ['Elisa', 2, 'Female', 20, 7],
    ['Robert', 3, 'Male', 7, 3],
    ['John', 4, 'Male', 54, 2],
    ['Jessica', 5, 'Female', 22, 6],
    ['Aaron', 6, 'Male', 3, 1],
    ['Margareth', 7, 'Female', 42, 8],
    ['Miranda', 8, 'Female', 33, 6]
  ]);

  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
  var options = {
    sort: 'event'
  };

  // table sort event
  google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'sort', function (sender) {
    // get sorted rows indexes
    var sortIndexes = data.getSortedRows({column: sender.column, desc: !sender.ascending});

    // move values to top
    moveToTop(sender, sortIndexes, 'Elisa');
    moveToTop(sender, sortIndexes, 'Michael');

    // set table sort arrow
    options.sortAscending = sender.ascending;
    options.sortColumn = sender.column;

    // build table view with custom sort
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setRows(sortIndexes);

    // draw table with view
    table.draw(view, options);
  });

  // move value to top of sort
  function moveToTop(sender, sortIndexes, value) {
    // find value in current sort
    var fixedRows = data.getFilteredRows([{
      column: 0,
      value: value
    }]);
    if (fixedRows.length > 0) {
      // move value to top
      sortIndexes.splice(sortIndexes.indexOf(fixedRows[0]), 1);
      sortIndexes.unshift(fixedRows[0]);
    }
  }

  // first draw
  table.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table"></div>
```